# Items not in the aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to get the latest entry (timestamp) for each barcode. I can get the query, but it won't let me get the other columns.

For example:

```
Barcode Name Timestamp
123     Jeff Today
123     Jeff Yesterday
342     Bill Today
342     Bill Yesterday
```

The result I'm looking for:

```
Barcode Name Timestamp
123     Jeff Today
342     Bill Yesterday
```

Here is my command:

```
 SELECT 
 x.Barcode,
 x.FullName,
 x.Location,
 MAX(x.Timestamp)

 FROM [DB].[dbo].[Inventory] x
 JOIN (SELECT p.Barcode,
             MAX(Timestamp) AS Timestamp
        FROM [DB].[dbo].[Inventory] p
     GROUP BY p.Barcode) y ON y.Barcode = x.Barcode
                          AND y.Timestamp = x.Timestamp
 GROUP BY x.Barcode, x.Timestamp
```

It tells me:

```
Column 'DB.dbo.Inventory.FullName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Would I need to do a join? I'm using a single nonnormalized table.

Comment: You don't need to do another `GROUP BY`, just the `JOIN` will work: `SELECT x.Barcode, x.FullName, x.Location, x.Timestamp FROM ()...`

Answer (score 2):

Columns which are not in Aggregate Function you should include it in Select clause at Least in `SQL server`

```
 SELECT 
 x.Barcode,
 x.FullName,
 x.Location,
 MIN(x.Timestamp)

 FROM [DB].[dbo].[Inventory] x
 JOIN (SELECT p.Barcode,
             MAX(Timestamp) AS Timestamp
        FROM [DB].[dbo].[Inventory] p
     GROUP BY p.Barcode) y ON y.Barcode = x.Barcode
                          AND y.Timestamp = x.Timestamp
 GROUP BY x.Barcode,x.FullName,
 x.Location
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the ranking function [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx) to get the latest record for each barcode:

```
SELECT  BarCode, FullName, Location, TimeStamp
FROM    (   SELECT  BarCode, 
                    FullName, 
                    Location, 
                    TimeStamp,
                    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BarCode 
                                                ORDER BY Timestamp DESC)
            FROM    [DB].[dbo].[Inventory]
        ) AS t
WHERE   RowNum = 1;
```